# Homebrew error while installing postgresql

Tags: postgresql, macos, homebrew

I'm trying to install Postgresql with Homebrew on MacOS. After this command:

```
brew install postgresql
```

I get this error:

```
Updating Homebrew...
error: Not a valid ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'refs/remotes/origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eurror!

Welcome to the stack overflow,

I also faced this error while installing `PostgreSQL` using `Homebrew`,
Homebrew is a decent package manager but using this every time is not convenient
I suggest you should download it from, https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads

Here you can download the package for your compatible version, then there are some tiny steps to install `PostgreSQL`

HaPpY Coding